# Specify SSL timeout with requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm noticing on some logs that I'm receiving an SSLError `'The read operation timed out'` just over a second after all the data has been read and uploaded from a file during a PUT upload request.

I've tried increasing the timeout by passing a higher value `requests.put(url, filename, timeout=60)`, but I guess this isn't getting passed to the SSL part of the underlying library? as it still times out at just over a second as it did before.

Is there a way to increase the timeout for the SSL part of the request from 1 second (it appears to be 1 second anyway)